# Set Data Range on Filemaker after search

Tags: filemaker

After searching on Filemaker, I get 100 search results. I would like to get last 10 record only. How do you set a script?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the script step Omit Multiple Records and then enter the number of records you want to omit from the found set, counting from the active record.